# Find the lowest or highest value between two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns. How can I use conditional formatting to highlight only the lowest or highest value?

```
 A        B
$6.05   $4.60 
$6.05   $4.60 
$7.25   $6.30 
$6.05   $4.60 
$6.05   $4.60 
$7.55   $8.10 
$6.05   $4.60 
$7.70   $6.30 
$6.05   $4.60
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I've edited your post to include the [microsoft-excel] tag because it appears to be about Excel. If my assumption is mistaken, please edit your question to include the appropriate tags.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have accidentally come across this question, if it's still actual, here's the solution:

1. Select all columns with data.
2. To highlight the highest values, create a conditional formatting rule with this formula:
   `=A1=MAX($A$1:$B$200)`

Where `A1` is the upper-left cell with your data (please notice the use of a relative reference), and `$A$1:$B$200` is the data range (absolute references are used here).

[image] 
3. Make a second rule for the min value with this formula:
`=A1=MAX($A$1:$B$200)`

We you have little or no experience with Excel conditional formatting, the detailed guidelines are here: How to create a conditional formatting rule with a formula
[How to create a conditional formatting rule with a formula](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/)